# using android native autocorrect with custom ime

Tags: android, ime, autocorrect

I'm considering writing an application for text input on android an I'm curious if there is a way to use android inbuilt dictionary and auto correct systems. I would really like to leave these parts to be native to android while rewriting the input.

Comment: Hey Dakun, did you manage to find a solution to this?